# Dedicated Server for Unity using Mirror and Lightsail

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-lightsail, unity3d-mirror

I am running into issues when attempting to run the built Server.x86_64 when running it on lightsail. My output when running './Server.x86_64' in the server directory is:

```
[UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=4194304"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-job-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-preload-manager=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-cloud-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gfx=262144"
```

I don't get any message saying the server started or anything. I am using a KCP transport through Mirror and put up a basic Lightsail Linux Server. I built the dedicated server code using the following:

```
[MenuItem("Build/Build Server (Linux)")]
public static void BuildLinuxServer()
{
    BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
    buildPlayerOptions.scenes = new[] { "Assets/Scenes/Main.unity" };
    buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = "Builds/Linux/Server/Server.x86_64";
    buildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.StandaloneLinux64;
    buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.CompressWithLz4HC | BuildOptions.EnableHeadlessMode;

    Console.WriteLine("Building Server (Linux)...");
    BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);
    Console.WriteLine("Built Server (Linux).");
}
```

Let me know if you need any other info. For reference, I was following a tutorial on Youtube which may be helpful to know.

Comment: I dont think it does say anything. Unless you make it. Its a server end no point showing spam no one is looking at

Comment: I am just checking to see if it is running. It doesn't seem to be since I am trying to connect and it just times out...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that has troubles with this I found the answer here. Basically, Unity 2021 changed the way they handle headless servers. So, if you are using a script (like I did from the Shrine tutorial), you should change this:

```
buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.CompressWithLz4HC | BuildOptions.EnableHeadlessMode;
```

to this:

```
buildPlayerOptions.subtarget = (int)(StandaloneBuildSubtarget.Server);
```

This is in BuildScript. Also make sure to open 7777 port for UDP if using KCP transport.

Comment: Thanks for the update I upvoted it. I'm interested in doing something similar, did it work well ?